# Overflow and carry flag when adding values to registers

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cpu-registers, flags

I'm working with the following code in Visual Studio:

```
mov ax,7ff0h

add ax,10h              ; AX = 8000h PL = 1 ZR = 0 CY = 0 OV = 1
add ah,1                ; AX = 8100h PL = 1 ZR = 0 CY = 0 OV = 0
add ax,2                ; AL = 02h   PL = 1 ZR = 0 CY = 0 OV = 0
```

And I'm finding that when I add 10h to the ax register, I get an Overflow Flag. I'm pretty sure this is because 8000h = 32768d which exceeds the bounds of a signed integer.

Yet when it comes to adding 1d(01h) to the ah register, I find that ax = 8100h, which is equivalent to 33024d, yet there is no Overflow Flag thrown. I'm a little confused and just want to know why this is. Could anyone explain how the overflow and carry flag work in a situation such as this and why an overflow flag isn't being thrown for the second op?

Answer (score 0):

The starting value of AH for the second instruction is 0x80 which when treated as signed 8-bit twos complement converts to the decimal number -128. Adding 1 to this produces 0x81 which is -127. You have added 1 to -128 and gotten -127. There is no overflow.

Comment: Could you tell me exactly why we are referencing to the 2s complement of the value 80h in order to determine if it's overflow flag is set?

Comment: Because the x86 ADD instruction is defined such that the OF flag reflects overflow in signed addition. (The CF flag reflects carry, or borrow, in unsigned addition.) But note also that in unsigned addition, this is an add of 1 to 128 producing 129. Also no carry (CF). 0x7f is 127 but adding 1 produces -128 in 8-bit signed, hence overflow (OF), but it is 127 + 1 = 128 in unsigned, hence no carry. 0xFF + 1 is -1 + 1 = 0 in 8-bit signed, thus no OF, but 255 + 1 = 0 in unsigned, thus CF would be set.